# JRE issue on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm not sure what keeps happening but everytime there is a new issue.
I'm getting an error :

```
Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre.
Required by:
    project : > org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.15.0 > org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:4.15.0
    project : > org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.15.0 > org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:4.15.0
    project : > org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.15.0 > org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:4.15.0 > org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-http:4.15.0
```

Sometimes it is a version mismatch, sometimes something else. I tried recreating a new project but this issue is still there. Is there any way to resolve this? Or refresh the whole project so no issues with dependency mismatch or any fundamental issue?

Tried reloading gradle, google repo for dependencies and anything else I could find on google.

Edit:
Build file :

```
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.11.0'
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.4.0'
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.22'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    implementation group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-testng', version: '2.17.1'

}

test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

Comment: Did you declare any repositories in your build file(s)? You should probably at least have something like mavenCentral() declared in there, See e.g. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: Sharing your build file(s) here could also be a good idea; then people can have a look at them and maybe figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.11.0'
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.4.0'
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.22'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    implementation group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-testng', version: '2.17.1'

}

test {
    useTestNG()
}

Comment: If the suggestions above won't help try wiping Gradle cache. I've tested both 4.11.0 and 4.15.0 and Gradle seems processing both just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after changing the selenium version to 4.11.0